# Using std::bit_cast on a std::vector underlying buffer with compatible layout

Tags: c++, wrapper

I need to wrap a C library using integer identifiers for different kinds of entities in a C++ library.
What I'd like to achieve with my library is both type safety and efficiency at the same time (ideally zero overhead).

The native C library has functions similar to the following:

```
int ps_get_bodies_bounds(int const* bodies, int size, ...);
int ps_get_faces_bounds(int const* faces, int size, ...);
```

As you can see, `int`s are used all over the place to represent every kind of entity.

In my C++ library, I want to use the type system to express those different entities:

```
class Body
{
   public:

      constexpr Body() noexcept
      {
         // enforce at compile time that this class
         // must be just a strongly typed integer
         static_assert(sizeof(Body) == sizeof(int));
      }

      // ... public API ...

   private:
      int m_tag{ 0 };
};

class Face
{
   // similar to what has been done for 'Body'
};
```

One of the aims of the C++ wrapper is also that clients can use contiguous memory containers like `std::vector` to store entities and operate on them:

```
wrapper::Bounds wrapper::get_bounds(std::vector<Body> const& bodies);
wrapper::Bounds wrapper::get_bounds(std::vector<Face> const& faces);
```

The wrapper should of course call the underlying C function and, ideally, I'd like to be able to pass the memory held by the vector directly for efficiency reasons:

```
wrapper::Bounds wrapper::get_bounds(std::vector<Body> const& bodies)
{
   // ...

   // OF COURSE, DOES NOT COMPILE
   auto err = ps_get_bodies_bounds(bodies.data(), static_cast<int>(bodies.size()), ...);

   // ...
}
```

Written in this way, the code of course does not compile because `bodies.data()` returns a `Body const*` type instead of an `int const*`.

Is it a well-defined behavior/safe/portable to use `std::bit_cast` in this case?

```
ps_get_bodies_bounds(std::bit_cast<int const*>bodies.data(), ...);
```

If yes, would it work even for view-types like a `std::span<Body>`?

Note that I am forcing at compile time that the size of `Body`, `Face`, etc... matches the one of an `int`.

I have tried this approach on Compiler Explorer with GCC, Clang, and MSVC and it seems to work (the code is a bit more complex than what I've explained here but the core concept is the same). I'm not sure though if it's a valid use of `std::bit_cast` or if it's UB. Here's the link to Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/44GWc7PYs.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: No, you cannot use `bit_cast` to cast from one pointer type to another and expect to end up with a valid pointer. If I understand correctly, what you want is to reinterpret the array of `Body`s as an array of `int`s. As far as I know this is always undefined behaviour according to the C++ standard. However in practice you should be fine with a simple `reinterpret_cast<int const*>(bodies.data())`, especially if the the C code is compiled seperately from the C++ code. I would be surprised if any existing compiler did something funny with this, it's just that the standard gives no guarantees.

Comment: C++23 provides the [`start_lifetime_as` and `start_lifetime_as_array` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as), which would explicitly bless the use of reinterpret cast. If you use C++23 or plan to migrate use could use this.

Comment: @chrysante While officially that would be UB, but I agree with your assesment.  If it works for your compiler, write compile time tests (already done) and unit tests to quickly catch any change in (compiler) behavior later.

Comment: Another options is not to let Body be the int directly. But to give body a  static std::vector<int> as member of the body class and each body instance then refers to an index in this vector. And it can operate on that.

Comment: Not the way you mentioned. Keep data as `std::vector<int>` in memory and provide an interface function for C++ code: `auto body_wrap::cpp_view()const{ return int_vec | std::views::transform([](auto x){return std::bit_cast<body>(x);});};` you can template the wrapper on element type. This only provides read-only access. But you can provide write/modify interface functions too. Needs a bit of thought, but results in efficient and safe code.

Comment: Instead of `body` you can create a `my_ref<body>` template and use that in transformation. The semantics of `my_ref` can be similar to `std::bitset::reference` or `std:: vector<bool>::reference`. This removes the immutablity constraints from the interface function.

Comment: @chrysante: Note that you’d have to bless them back to the original type before letting the `vector` destroy them.

Comment: @DavisHerring how can I bless them back? Should I use again `std::start_lifetime_as_array<Body>` or is it a use case for `std::launder` or something else?
Sorry, but these features are quite unclear to me even after looking at cppreference.

Comment: @StefanoBellotti: I *think* the further `std::start_lifetime_as_array` would work; this area comprises many subtle points, though.

Comment: @DavisHerring OK, thanks for your help.